# Structuring a Game with Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, web-development, web-applications, game-development, angularjs

For a GameJam I'm trying to code a simple web-based text adventure game with sprites and small animations in AngularJS. I'm a little new to Angular and am having some trouble figuring out how to structure it. I think my trouble comes from my struggle with `Controllers` vs `Directives`.

My game essentially needs to pull text from a text file and display it within a `DOM element` when clicked. Accompanying that is a separate `DOM` item that displays a character sprite image.  When certain bits of text are displayed, the image needs to animate.

Can anyone who knows `AngularJS` well walk me through the most clean and efficient way to structure this between my `controllers`, `directives`, and the HTML view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `directives` for the DOM elements and `controllers` for interaction between these `directives`. DOM manipulation should only be done inside a `directive`.

Fetching a text file could be done inside the controller, but it would be better if you did that through a `service`. Services can be used for reusable business logic/fetching data.

You could see it as the MVC pattern. Model/business-logic can be put in a `service`, View is composed of normal HTML elements and `directives` and the Controller who orchestrates communication between the two.